# Minor scale pattern played on Guitar

Tags: scales

What is the pattern for pentatonic minor scales, I know that the pattern for major scales is "W W H WWW H.
So what is the pattern in that short-hand for the minor scales?

Answer (score 1):

It would be `(W+H) W W (W+H) W` Where the (W+H) represents a step and a half or 3 half steps.

But I find it easier and more common to define it as degrees relative to the parallel major scale. So if a major scale is:

`1  2  3  4  5  6  7`

Then a Minor Pentatonic is:

`1    b3  4  5    b7`

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there are different minor scales. The main ones being:

*Pentatonic minor - WH W W WH W.

*Natural minor - W H W W H W W .

*Harmonic minor - W H W W H WH H.

*Melodic minor - W H W W W W H.

Melodic minor is shown as the jazz melodic, same up and down. The classical melodic, featured in a lot of exams, is shown rising. Going down, it is played as the natural minor.

Comment: Thanks for this information!!! I only learnt the minor pentatonic scale, not all the other ones you have listed here.